Understanding polygonal approach for procedural generation of roads and rivers
First of all, I have already discovered these questions and their answers:
Road / river generation on 2d grid map
Algorithms for rainfall + river creation in procedurally generated terrain
Generating lakes and rivers on 2D grid
Many math-related articles on generation of Voronoi diagrams, Random Walk etc. are difficult for me to understand. It's even more difficult to pick a solution from among them. For the generation of the map itself I use simplex noise, which is great for generation of biomes, but is not well-suited to the generation of water terrain. Using noise values for determining the water level results in generation of chaotically placed water regions which mostly look like small lakes.
What I want is to create one curved line on the tile map, start-to-end coordinates of which are random points on the edges of the map. I search for a simple algorithm for random generation of points on the map, to be connected as a graph, creating a sharp-edged path. After that, I assume something like La Grange interpolation will do the work on creating a more curved path.
UPDATE:
To clarify my struggle, here is the general question I have after reading Amit's work on Polygonal Map Generation for Games: How do I apply that approach to tilemaps, especially the rivers' locations since they are basically the lines connecting corners of polygons? It is unclear to me how tiles will relate to polygons and their corners.

@DMGregory what I don't understand (eventhough it might be simple) is why do I even need Voronoi polygons to approach procedural generation regarding rivers/roads? It seems like a highlighted solution but I don't know why

Anyway, I updated my question to be more clear about the problematic parts

The Voronoi part is usually just for making the underlying grid less obvious. Voronoi cells look more organic than a square grid. If you don't care about that for your use case, skip it. The island determination is in the earlier section "Islands" and the project provides source code so you can inspect the specific function he used in his version. I notice none of the three questions you've highlighted mention roads or rivers. Do you want to edit your question to ask how to apply this method to a tilemap? (That is, to ask only that: one question per post).

@DMGregory I edited my question

If you're using square tiles, a square is a polygon with 4 corners, so there seems to be a pretty natural mapping from polygon corners to tile corners. Can you elaborate on what you find confusing about this? Maybe diagram what you tried and what's not working?

@DMGregory that is actually answering my question, so should I close/delete this question?

I'd recommend testing out this idea to see how it works for you. If you like the results, you can post your own answer, showing how you implemented your river generation and the results you got. If not, you can refine your question and show what you still need help with.

I don't think "random" is an effective strategy. Random generation still involves (very) many "rules"; even touching on player skill levels. "Random" might be the initial placement of a Town Center; after that, eveything is by formula. How many "berry bushes". Min / max for their location. Number of roads in and out. Small rivers or "wide" rivers. Plains or hills. Trees or shrubs. Etc.

@GerrySchmitz I completely understand that world generation is usually restricted by some specific rules. For now I just want to test out different solutions and then I can start working on corresponding to game-specific patterns


First of all, I have already discovered these questions and their
answers:

Then you'll have read and understood Amit Patel's crystal clear description of this topic, as posted by House in the answers linked, not so? He goes through everything, including roads and rivers.
Study that well, and ask for clarifications on that, since that holds all that you need to know about the creation of rivers and roads, if you keep reading. Amit's work is a treasure trove.

For the generation of the map itself I use simplex noise, which is
great for generation of biomes, but is not very suitable for
generation of water terrain. Using noise value of determining the
water level results in generation of chaotic-placed water regions
which mostly look like small lakes.

These algorithms produce values which can be treated as heights, not primarily colours / terrain type  IDs which is what you are probably currently getting, based on your mention of "small lakes". Using those heights, you can then:
(2D) clamp() to the necessary minimum height for sea level, and to get large islands and continents, by e.g. newHeight = clamp(oldHeight, seaLevel, maxHeight) (or by using a combination of max and min functions) to bring the value into a predefined range, thereby producing large, flat, low-lying areas which you will then colour accordingly as ocean; size of continents and islands is decided by the height of the sea level;
OR
(3D) generate full heightmap without clamping, including the underwater heightmap topography, decide where in that range the sea-level lies, and produce (animated) mesh for the ocean surface.

Unfortunately your initial comment seemed a little harsh one, I did not downvote this though. So I mean no disrespect. I edited my question and asked for clarifications as you advised. Please review them

after all I realized that for my specific game desing I don't need polygonal approach. Some points of your answer helped me with my exact goals, so thank you very much

@Steyrix You are welcome! Enjoy.
